# Find a basis for $V^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Given a vector space $V$ with a basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3....,.....,e_n\}$. Construct a basis for $V^m=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m| v_i \in V\}$.

I was thinking of something like $(0,0,\ldots,e_i,0,\ldots)$ where $1 \le i \le m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define basis to be a spanning set, your $E = \{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ will do. If your basis also needs to be linearly independent, apply Gaussian Elimination to solve $E X = V^m$ and pick all the $e_i$ which have at least one non-zero coefficient anywhere in the resulting $X$ matrix.